# Check if a given data lies between two particular dates inside a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, database, date

I have a DataTable `dt` with two columns `FromDate` and `ToDate`. I have two textboxes where I am entering the dates `blackOutFromDate` and `blackOutToDate`. Say, I have 7 rows inside my DataTable `dt`:

```
From Date       To Date      
8/21/2012   To  8/22/2012   
8/23/2012   To  8/24/2012   
8/25/2012   To  8/25/2012   
8/5/2012    To  8/6/2012    
8/26/2012   To  8/27/2012   
8/1/2012    To  8/2/2012    
8/3/2012    To  8/3/2012
```

If the value that I enter inside my text boxes `CheckInDate` and `CheckOutDate` is between any matching date range of DataTable `dt`, it should return the count of the noumber of rows having such match.

I am doing

```
foundRows = _blackOutTable.Select
                               (
                                   "(FromDate <='" +     
blackOutFromDate.ToShortDateString() + "' AND ToDate >= '" + 
blackOutFromDate.ToShortDateString() + "')"
                                   + "OR (FromDate <='" + 
blackOutToDate.ToShortDateString() + "' AND ToDate >='" + 
blackOutToDate.ToShortDateString() + "')"
                                   + "OR (FromDate >='" + 
blackOutFromDate.ToShortDateString() + "' AND FromDate <='" +     
blackOutToDate.ToShortDateString() + "')"
                                   + "OR (ToDate >= '" +   
blackOutFromDate.ToShortDateString() + "' AND ToDate <='" +     
blackOutToDate.ToShortDateString() + "')"
                               );
if (foundRows.Length == 0)
{
}
```

EDIT :
I am storing the DateFrom and DateTo filed inside SQl Server as

```
CAST(MONTH(date1) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(DAY(date1) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' +     
CAST(YEAR(date1) AS VARCHAR(4))  [fromdate],
        CAST(MONTH(date2) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(DAY(date2) AS 
VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(date2) AS VARCHAR(4))  [todate]
```

blackOutFromDate and blackOutFromDate are of DateTime types.

But it's not returning the correct values. There is some problem with the select expression. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>This is the [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) syntax `for` `DateTimes`:</strike>

```
foundRows = _blackOutTable.Select("FromDate >= #2012-07-13#")
```

So you need to use `String.Format` to put your date variable into that string.

**Edit**: Since your datetimes are converted to varchar and you cannot change that, you need to parse them back to datetime. I would recommend to use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
DataTable tblFiltered;
var invCulture=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var filteredRows = _blackOutTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<String>("FromDate"), invCulture) >= blackOutFromDate
             && DateTime.Parse(r.Field<String>("ToDate"),   invCulture) <= blackOutToDate);

if (filteredRows.Any())
{
    tblFiltered = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

You can use `foreach` to enumerate all rows or use `CopyToDataTable` to create a new `DataTable` from the filtered `DataRows`.

Comment: I already did 
var blackOutFromDate = DateTime.Parse(CheckInDate.Text);
var blackOutToDate = DateTime.Parse(CheckOutDate.Text);

Comment: I am getting this error :
system.data.enumerablerowcollection <system.data.datarow> does not contain definition of Any()

Comment: Have you added `using System.Linq; `?

Comment: when the debugger reaching line if(filteredRows.Any()) , it is throwing an exception :"Specified Cast is not valid"

Comment: What type are `FromDate` and `ToDate`? You exception might be raised because these are not `DateTimes` but - for instance - `Strings`. Then you need to parse them to dates first. I will show you an example then.

Comment: I even converted  FromDate and ToDate to DateTime ..But still no success.

Comment: @palakmehta: So i assume that _"no success"_ atcually means `filteredRows.Any()` returns false and you're sure that the filter should return rows?

Comment: when the debugger is reaching line if(filteredRows.Any()) , it is throwing an exception :"Specified Cast is not valid

Comment: :My aim is to  insert a insert a record in the datatable _blackOutTable in my case , only when the records that I am entering blackOutFromDate and blackOutToDate should not lie between any date range(FromDate and ToDate) that are inside the DataTable.

Comment: e.g.
FromDate         ToDate    
8/21/2012   To  8/22/2012   
/
then I should not enter the record blackOutFromDate=8/22/2012 and blackOutToDate =8/23/2012 
Where as I can  enter the record blackOutFromDate=8/24/2012 and blackOutToDate =8/25/2012

Comment: You can use `filteredRows.CopyToDataTable()` to convert the result to a new DataTable. The reson for the `InvalidCastException` is that one of the dates(or both) is not a DateTime in the DataTable. So you need to show me how it gets filled. Do you use a `DataAdapter` or are you filling it manually? What dbms are you using, SQL-Server? Is it really `datetime` on database side?

Comment: I am storing it as :
CAST(MONTH(date1) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(DAY(date1) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(date1) AS VARCHAR(4))  [fromdate],
   CAST(MONTH(date2) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(DAY(date2) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(date2) AS VARCHAR(4))  [todate]

Comment: Because , it was my requirement.I cannot do any changes on DB Side ..I am using SQL Server DB

Comment: @palakmehta: Then you have the reason for your problems. If you want to filter by these dates, you should not convert them to string. You can convert them to the monthnames in the application.  Or you should also select the original datetime columns in the query. **Edit** Does your last comment mean that you cannot change the query, is that a stored-procedure that you cannot change?

Comment: It is done inside an sp and it cant be changed..I have some other restrictions too..
Can can I do some workaround in  c# code/.cs file?

Comment: I dont have any issues accepting the answers , but I would really appreciate it , if you could give me a solution.

Comment: @palakmehta: I've edited my answer to show a working way to parse your strings back to datetime and filter by them.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this on the database ?

```
WHERE (1=1) 
AND 
( 
    @in_ReportingDate BETWEEN Cast(Floor(Cast(ZO_RMArea_DateFrom As Float)) As DateTime) AND Cast(Floor(Cast(ZO_RMArea_DateTo As Float)) As DateTime) 
    OR ZO_RMArea_DateFrom IS NULL 
    OR ZO_RMArea_DateTo IS NULL 
)
```

Also caution - you have DateTime values, if you do ToShortDateString, it will be date.00:00:00.000, while FromDate can be date.23:59:59.995

That's what Cast(Floor(Cast is for. To truncate the time in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int rowCount = blackOutTable.AsEnumerable()
            .Count(c => ((DateTime)c["FromDate"]) >= blackOutFromDate && ((DateTime)c["ToDate"]) <= blackOutToDate);
```

Comment: >NET PRO  :I am getting an exception , when I am executing this line of code